# Двухуровневое меню PHP+MYSQL

Tags: меню, php, mysql

Добрый день, господа.

Есть задача: нужно из 2-х таблиц в базе сделать двухуровневое меню. Первая таблица имеет названия пунктов основного меню, вторая таблица содержит названия модулей, которые выступают в качестве пунктов подменю. Столкнулся с проблемой создания именно этих пунктов подменю.

```
public function create(){
    $real_menu = array();
    $menu = $this->get('menu');
    $module = $this->get('modules');

    foreach($menu as $value){
        $real_menu[$value['id']] = $value;
    }
    foreach ($module as $value) {
            $real_menu[$value['menu_id']]['child'] = $value;
        }

    return $real_menu;
}
```

По идее, первым циклом мы заполняем массив основными пунктами меню, второй цикл добавляет в массив еще один элемент с набором массивов с пунктами подменю. Однако на выходе я получаю следующую картину:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Управление
        [sort] => 0
        [child] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [module_name] => Все Пользователи
                [url] => allusers
                [descr] => Отображение всех пользователей
                [menu_id] => 1
                [allow] => 1
                [sort] => 1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Настройки
        [sort] => 0
        [child] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [module_name] => Права пользователей
                [url] => userperms
                [descr] => Права пользователей
                [menu_id] => 2
                [allow] => 1
                [sort] => 3
            )

    )
```

Другими словами, добавляется с таблицы только последний элемент подменю, который есть в базе.
Помогите разобраться, буду очень благодарен.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать так, у нас же получается массив с массивами:

```
foreach ($module as $value) {
  $real_menu[$value['menu_id']]['child'][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает=)